# Get Base64 from imageURI with PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, cordova, base64

I'm trying to get the base64 from an image that picked from the album on my phone, but I cannot make it work:

I tried this:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    console.log("0");
    fileSystem.root.getFile(imageURI, null, function(fileEntry) {
        console.log("1");
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            console.log("2");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                console.log("Read complete!");
                image64.value = Base64.encode(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, failFile);
    }, failFile);
}, failSystem);
```

Although the image is displayed correctly.. I receive an error from this function:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(imageURI, null, function(fileEntry)
```

And the error is: **FileError.ENCODING_ERR**

I know that code doesn't look pretty. But I don't know how to get the Base64 encoding from an imageURI.

Comment: hi its easy already give example just ref... this link.. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280911/encoding-a-image-to-base64-and-upload-to-web-service-in-phonegap/22910216#22910216)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/c476b2224ddd2003/40843cb225062089?lnk=gst&q=%28new%20Date%28%29%29.getTime%28%29#40843cb225062089). I modified it a little bit and this is the result:

```
var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) { 
    console.log("got image file entry: " +  fileEntry.fullPath); 
    fileEntry.file( function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read complete!");
            image64.value = Base64.encode(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }, failFile);
};

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, failSystem);
```

**NOTE:** It takes about 20 seconds to read a normal 5MPixel image and another 10-15 to Base64 encode it.

Comment: How to get base 64 string value? I want to save base 64 string to sqlite. How to use "image64.value".

Comment: @BM you can do it like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Answer (score 7):

The above method from SERPRO works...but i have to change

```
reader.readAsText(file);
to
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Thus, line

```
image64.value = Base64.encode(evt.target.result);
```

can be removed and the base64 result can be directly extracted as

```
image64.value = evt.target.result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cordova-plugin-file implements the [HTML5 File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/), and that uses callback API's. I prefer promises so I rewrote the method using the $q library:

```
function getContentAsBase64(fileUrl) {

  //Using $q to change the API so that getContentAsBase64 returns a promise
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  //function to call when either resolve or retrieval fails
  var fail = function (error) {
    errorHandler(error);
    deferred.reject(error);
  }

  //function to call when resolve file succeeded
  //we have a FileEntry - get the file, 
  var fileResolved = function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(fileSuccess, fail);
  }

  //function to call when file successfully retrieved
  //convert to base64 string
  var fileSuccess = function (file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
      //promise is resolved with the base64 string
      deferred.resolve(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, fileResolved, fail);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

> The [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-S/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method is used to read the contents of the
>   specified Blob or File. When the read operation is finished, the
>   readyState becomes DONE, and the loadend is triggered.At that time,
>   the result attribute contains the data as a URL representing the
>   file's data as a base64 encoded string.

Usage:

```
var imageData;
getContentAsBase64(aq.FileUri).then(function (content) {
   imageData= content;
});
```

Comment: @JorhelReyes https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q